# PHP parse error:syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_variable)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Please I need ask about the API code:

```php
<?php 
    // connection
    require('assets/connect.php');

    
    $finYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['finYear']);
    $branch = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['branch']);
    $handler = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['handler']);
    $member_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['member_id']);
    $months = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['months']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
    $transaction_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['transaction_id']);
    $payment = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['payment']);
    $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['amount']);
    $cat = 'fin';

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO paymentss (finYear, branch, handler, member_id, months, `name`, transaction_id, payment, amount, cat ) VALUES ('$finYear', '$branch', '$handler', '$member_id', '$months', '$name', '$transaction_id', '$payment', '$amount', '$cat')");

    if ($query) {
        $json = array("response" => "success", "status" => 1, "message" => "Successful");
    } else {
        $json = array("response" => "error", "status" => 0, "message" => "Error");
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);


?>
```

This is the error. It output:

> php parse error:syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_variable)

Comment: On which line does it say the error is? That is basic information you really ought to provide when reporting an error